# matching criteria and printing with awk

Tags: awk, printing, count

I have a file and I am trying to get this following information.
There are a few headers and my condition is as follows that returns the count of time "PO" is found in column 5.However I want to print the entries that match the criteria as well. How do I do that?

```
awk 'BEGIN {count = 0} $5 == "PO" && $13 <0.01 {count++} END {print(count)}' 1.genome
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have added your efforts in your post. Request you to please do add samples of input and sample expected output in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple things inside the curly braces.  If you keep it as a one-liner, separate each command by a semicolon.  E.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN {count = 0} $5 == "PO" && $13 <0.01 {print $0; count++} END {print count}' 1.genome
```

As the complexity grows, you may want to format it on multiple lines:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        count = 0
    } 

    $5 == "PO" && $13 < 0.01 {
        print $0
        count++
    } 

    END {
        print count
    }
' 1.genome
```

Comment: `print $0;` - you can just `print;`